# Auto generated block blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am observing that whenever I create a new folder inside the Azure blob storage, a block blob file with the same name as the folder is auto created. I dont know why and what setting is making this behave this way. Any pointers on why and how to disable this ? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please give us more information? For example, how do you create the folder, is it in the portal or using the sdk.

Comment: We are using Azure databricks and python code to access the storage container using the storage account key and creating the folders.

Comment: @VijayV, please let me know if you have any concerns about the answer below. And if it's helpful, please help accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @IvanYang - the issue is because the Hierarchical namespace was not enabled in that blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `azure blob storage`(not `Azure data lake storage Gen2`), you should know one important thing: You cannot create an empty folder. The reason is that blob storage has a 2 level hierarchy - `blob container` and `blob`. Any folder/directory should be part of a blob.

If you want to create an empty folder, you can use [Azure data lake storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) instead. It's built on blob storage and has some familiar operations.